# upgrade ICU version ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, nginx, php7

I have a problem installing symfony3 in php7, nginx and ubuntu 16.04, i have this error:

intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (55.1) and does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)
To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU system package and the intl PHP extension.

how can upgrade the ICU version to 57.1 in ubuntu 16.04?

Answer (score 0):

It was just a optional recommendation i run:

php bin/symfony_requirements

and everythink is ok .

[OK]
 Your system is ready to run Symfony projects

Optional recommendations to improve your setup
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

- intl ICU version installed on your system is outdated (55.1) and
  does not match the ICU data bundled with Symfony (57.1)
  To get the latest internationalization data upgrade the ICU
  system package and the intl PHP extension.

Comment: Ideally, the answer would answer the question. Did you work out how to upgrade the ICU?

Comment: A user in stack overflow post how to install ICU:
:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39377132/icu-version-compatibility-symfony-3-1.